# Is there a way to perform setup and cleanup on a story in Storybook?

Tags: reactjs, storybook

Is there a way to execute setup and cleanup steps for a story in Storybook?  Say, for example, I have a component that behaves differently contingent on the presence or value of some piece of local storage, or a property set on `window`.  I would like to be able to setup a story so that but also cleanup so that it does not inadvertently carry over to other stories.

If there is no official suggested best practice, I would think the best way to do this is to make a custom decorator that wraps the story in a component with setup and teardown lifecycle events (I am using Storybook with React in this case, FYI).  Open to other ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Decorators are the official recommendation for what you are describing. They can be added to an individual story, all stories for a component, or globally for all the stories.

Docs: https://storybook.js.org/docs/6.5/vue/writing-stories/decorators

Comment: we can use decorators to do setup work, but what about cleanup?